# Eclipse IDE Getting Webpage Error Popup "Do you want to debug this webpage"

Tags: eclipse, ide

I am working in Eclipse on existing projects. I am starting to get this Webpage Error popup. Does anyone know why this is happening? I have never experienced this popup before.

Example of Popup I get

[image: 1]

I shut down Eclipse and restarted it and it keeps coming back after about 5 minutes. I am on version Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (includes Incubating components)
Version: 2022-06 (4.24.0)
Build id: 20220609-1112
OS: Windows 10, v.10.0, x86_64 / win32
Java vendor: Eclipse Adoptium
Java runtime version: 17.0.1+12
Java version: 17.0.1

Comment: This could be caused by a view or an info pop-up that is using the browser widget. Based on the information given, it is not possible to tell what exactly is causing it. Anyhow, your Eclipse is more than a year and seven releases behind. Does upgrading to the current Eclipse version fix it? Otherwise, does checking _"Do not show the message again"_ fix it?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. It seemed to stop after a windows system update. Not sure if it was related. I will upgrade my version of Eclipse also based on your recommendation.